# missing header file in kernel-module compilation

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I am compiling my first Linux Kernel Module, when i got this error:

```
from hello-1.c:4:
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.38-8-generic/include/linux/prefetch.h:14:27: 
fatal error: asm/processor.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

What does this mean and how do I go about solving it?

Do i have to download and add some processor.h to the folder and if so, where can I get it ?

Comment: How exactly do you run compilation? If you do it through Kbuild, do you add `ARCH=...` flag to Make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when the path to the linux kernel is not provided thru the I flag of gcc